# Zipping Conda Environment Breaks Audioread's Backend (Python/Pyspark)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyspark, anaconda, conda

I have previously build pyspark environments using conda to package all dependancies and ship them to all the nodes at runtime. Here's how I create the environment:

```
`conda/bin/conda create -p conda_env --copy -y python=2  \
numpy scipy ffmpeg gcc libsndfile gstreamer pygobject audioread librosa`

`zip -r conda_env.zip conda_env`
```

Then sourcing `conda_env` and running `pyspark` shell I can successfully execute:

```
`import librosa
y, sr = librosa.load("test.m4a")`
```

Note without the environment sourced this script results in an error as ffmpeg/gstreamer are NOT installed on my locally.

Submitting a script to the cluster results in a `librosa.load` error which traces back to `audioread` indicating the backend (either gstreamer or ffmpeg) can no longer be found in the zipped archive environment. The stacktrace is below:

Submit:

```
`PYSPARK_PYTHON=./NODE/conda_env/bin/python spark-submit --verbose \
        --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./NODE/conda_env/bin/python \
        --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp \
        --conf spark.executorEnv.PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp \
        --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 \
        --conf spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs=false \
        --conf spark.driver.cores=5 \
        --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 \
        --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue production \
        --num-executors 20 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 40G \
        --driver-memory 20G --archives conda_env.zip#NODE \
        --jars /data/environments/sqljdbc41.jar \
        script.py`
```

Trace:

```
`Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1506634200253_39889/container_1506634200253_39889_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1506634200253_39889/container_1506634200253_39889_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1506634200253_39889/container_1506634200253_39889_01_000003/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "script.py", line 245, in <lambda>
  File "script.py", line 119, in download_audio
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1506634200253_39889/container_1506634200253_39889_01_000003/NODE/conda_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/core/audio.py", line 107, in load
    with audioread.audio_open(os.path.realpath(path)) as input_file:
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/user/appcache/application_1506634200253_39889/container_1506634200253_39889_01_000003/NODE/conda_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/audioread/__init__.py", line 114, in audio_open
    raise NoBackendError()
NoBackendError`
```

My question is: How can I package this archive so that librosa (really audioread) is able to find the backend and load .m4a files?

Answer (score 1):

This was a path issue, the executors could not find FFMPEG although it was packaged in the conda environment. This hack fixes it.

```
path = os.getenv("PATH")
if "./NODE/conda_env/bin" not in path:
    path += os.pathsep + "./NODE/conda_env/bin"
    os.environ["PATH"] = path
y, _ = librosa.load(audiofn, self.conf.sr)
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. Like you, I try librosa.load(), but get NoBackendError - even after your proposed solution.

Comment: @J.Dahlgren are you making the conda environment as shown? Couple of things to try, source the conda environment locally and do `which ffmpeg` to see if the env is created correctly. If that works you can shell out from your python program and execute the same command to see if ffmpeg is found on the executors.